# How can I test equality of two pthread mutexes?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I need to write a C++ wrapper over a pthread mutex and I'm having trouble implementing the operator==. Is there a way to get a unique ID of some sort for the pthread_mutex that I could use for the test?

**EDIT:**

To be more specific about what I'm trying to acheive I have the following:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex1;
pthread_mutex_t mutex2;
pthread_mutex_t mutex3;

pthread_mutex_init(&mutex1, NULL);
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex2, NULL);
mutex3 = mutex2;
```

I would like to have a `bool mutexCompare(pthread_mutex_t t1, pthread_mutex_t t2)` function which will return false for `mutexCompare(mutex1, mutex2)` and true for `mutexCompare(mutex2, mutex3)`

There already is an `int pthread_equal(ptrhead_t t1, pthread_t t2)` which does what I need for threads. I need a similar one for mutexes.

**EDIT:**

<strike>`mutex3 = mutex2;`</strike>

The above assignment is highly discouraged. POSIX documentation states that

> "There are no defined comparison or assignment operators for the types pthread_attr_t, pthread_cond_t, pthread_condattr_t, pthread_mutex_t, pthread_mutexattr_t, pthread_rwlock_t and pthread_rwlockattr_t."

The pthread_mutex_t objects(and others from the list) should be compared and assigned by their addresses.

Comment: It's always best to post some code with the exact problem you're having

Comment: What semantics are you expecting?  To my mind, `operator==` should probably compare the memory address of the `pthread_mutex_t` member, but you might e.g. want something that checks if they're both in the same locked/unlocked state.  It's relevant whether you expect to have these wrappers support copying, and if so with what ownership-of-the-mutex semantics.  For example, you might want any copy to initially have the new mutex reset, reflecting the idea that you'll copy a locked object then be the only accessor of the new object, with no need yet to arbitrate access.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. What does it mean for two mutexes to be equal? Of the same type and in the same state?

Comment: I need to port some Windows code to Linux. The Windows code uses `HANDLE` for all kinds of multi-threading primitives(and other stuff). An assignment from one `HANDLE` to another will not duplicate the referenced object. A == comparsion between two `HANDLE`s will tell if they reference the same object. I am writing a C++ class which emulates the `HANDLE` from Windows and I can't find a good way to implement the `operator==`

Comment: Note that you can't portably copy or assign `pthread_mutex_t` objects. From the POSIX spec: "There are no defined comparison or assignment operators for the types pthread_attr_t, pthread_cond_t, pthread_condattr_t, pthread_mutex_t, pthread_mutexattr_t, pthread_rwlock_t and pthread_rwlockattr_t".  You can compare and assign *pointers* to `pthread_mutex_t` objects, which would get you the equivalent of what you're describing with your use of `HANDLES` on Windows.

Comment: I see. Given that there is no assignment operator for `pthread_mutex_t` the assignment I made in my example `mutex3 = mutex2` is not very legal. If I am not doing any copies of the opaque structs then the address of the mutex is it's unique Id

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the `pthread_mutex_t` directly, since the only way to have two which are the same mutex is to explicitly copy one. There's no entirely robust way to compare two opaque types in C, but in C++ you should be able to just use `==` on the `pthread_mutex_t`s.

Alternatively, you could just have a static `int nextId`, and grab a unique ID every time you create a mutex wrapper from scratch; copy the id when you copy the wrapper. This, of course, only works if it's the wrapper itself which calls `pthread_mutex_init`, or if the user promises never to construct two wrappers from one mutex.

Comment: I tried == between the two opaque structs and I get "error: invalid operands to binary expression ('pthread_mutex_t' (aka '_opaque_pthread_mutex_t') and 'pthread_mutex_t')
  if (mutex2 == mutex3) {
"

Comment: Interesting -- they must be using some trick to force the type to be fully opaque. Use the ID thing, then.

Comment: I will go for the generated ids. Thanks!

Comment: Two mutexes in the same state could compare as equivalent even if they're distinct mutexes.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Not sure what you mean there. Since the IDs would be unique within a single program invocation, the only way for them to compare equal is if they were the result of the same constructor call -- in which case they're the same mutex. (Of course, the ID counter needs to be mutex-guarded itself.)

Comment: @Sneftel I'm talking about your first suggestion of just comparing the pthread_mutex_t's for equality. The unique ID is not necessary -- each pthread_mutex_t is already at a unique memory location and cannot be moved, so there's already a unique ID for each mutex.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Ahh, got it. I dunno, how might that happen? If `==` can't tell them apart, then how is `pthread_mutex_lock` supposed to? It's all academic, though.... the pthreads impl I looked at made `pthread_mutex_lock` a union, so no `==`. (Clever bastards.)

Comment: @Sneftel `pthread_mutex_lock` takes a pointer to the `pthread_mutex_t`. So two `pthread_mutex_t`'s could have the same value and compare equal (because their value is "standard mutex, unlocked") but still be distinct mutexes because they live at different addresses.